# Match unmatched part of string by regexp

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have a string as HTML like this...

```
Lorem Ipsum<span class="removed">removed</span><span class="added">added </span>lorem ipsum
```

I would like to put strings that not in a span so I want it like

```
<span class="normal">Lorem Ipsum</span><span class="removed">removed</span><span class="added">added </span><span class="normal">lorem ipsum</span>
```

I can decompose all string and combine again with some lines of code, but I am asking that if that is possible with regex?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably yes - **however**, using regex to split HTML code is considered bad practice, and you should rather use DOM methods for splitting it.

Comment: you are right, but for this situation that is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that regexp is simplified for particular case and may be improved to handle more complex cases (cdata, comment, quotes, etc.)

search

```
<span(?>[^>]*>.*?<\/span>)(*SKIP)(?!)|([^<]*)
```

replace with

```
<span class="normal">\1</span>
```

[regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/qXzjEG/1/)

How it works

- 1 : match want we don't want `<span(?>[^>]*>.*?<\/span>)`
- 2 : using backtracking verbs to avoid backtracking and have a failed match `(*SKIP)(?!)`
- 3 : next in the alternation choose a pattern which can't match first part